# How can I add a jQuery event when my content is loaded dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$("#menu, #home")
    .on('click', 'a[href^="/C"], a[href^="/City"], 
       function (event) {
```

However the contents of #menu are dynamically loaded.

```
<div id="cityList" class="columns menu-list">
   <ul id="menu" class="controls-buttons question-grid">
      <li> </li>
      ......
      ......
```

How can I make it so the above jQuery works even if the #menu contents are not there yet?

Comment: I don't follow. How it can it work when the list is not there at the time the .on even is attached? I need something for dynamic.

Comment: maybe your jquery version is lower than 1.7

Comment: Okay the version might be the problem. Thanks :-)